# Graph representation of polymer nanocomposites

Tags: cheminformatics

Graph theory has been used as a means of representing molecules for decades. For a single molecule, a graph representation assigns a vertex for every atom in the molecule and the covalent bonds are represented using edges of the graph, which connect the pairs of vertices. I was wondering if there are established representation for multi-component materials as a single graph, in particular polymer nanocomposites?

Comment: Just because Lewis formulas *look* like graphs doesn´t mean they are, or rather that you can gain much by treating them as such. I´m afraid you are reasoning by analogy. Nanocomposites can (and are) often be characterised as network structures, that´s of course correct. How useful that is depends on what you want to know about them!

Comment: @Karl They in fact are frequently used in machine learning. Machine learning algorithms rely on some representation of the molecules. Graphs and SMILES are the frequently used representation methods to train these models.

Comment: Hm, I don´t know much about the current state of such methods. You should perhaps ask yourself what machine learning can do (=is good at) when describing molecules with graphs, and if your questions are somewhat similar. You don´t want to be the prototypical  man with a hammer, who sees nothing but nails. ;-)

Comment: Maybe you want to provide an example, and I agree with Karl, without specifying what property you are attempting to teach your method to correlate with whatever graph representation you come up with, then it seems you aren't providing enough information. I would say that any sort of abstract representation (molecular formula, dimensions, physical and chemical properties etc) that ultimately correlates in some unique way with the property of interest would provide useful predictive power.

Comment: @BuckThorn What you are referring to is supervised learning: you associate input with some value/class and train a model to do prediction. There is another category called unsupervised learning: you learn from the data itself. You can think about face generation networks, you train with many pictures of faces, algorithm learns what does a human face look like and generates new human faces. No value/label is associated with the training data. In chemistry, you can train a model with drug molecules and learn what a drug looks like and produce a new drug molecule.

Comment: I'm not quite up to date with AI. Has non-supervised machine learning *ever* been shown to work? Because even humans are terrible at it. ;-) Basically science and technology evolve because we are a swarm intelligence where each individual is able to learn almost arbitrary things, under supervision. That enables rare strokes of luck/genius to propagate, while they would otherwise flicker and be gone.

Comment: Ah, of course! Writing 'ever' in italic won't help with the philosophical argument. It's all statistics. If you learn distribution of an event, you can sample from that distribution and have new samples of the same nature. But let's not get sidetracked.

Comment: ;-) Putting aside the philosophicals, what do you (intend your computer to) learn nonsupervised? How do you "grade" (t)his learning, or put it to task?

Comment: The objective can come in the form of reconstruction of the training data. For instance, VAEs learn to extract features from the input data and then learn to reconstruct the input from those features. They are trained based on how good their reconstruction was.

Comment: Why go from drugs to "polymer nanocomposites". Seems quite a leap. What about everything inbetween?

Comment: Mind to elaborate?

Comment: There are a lot of additional features you'd need to capture moving to a composite. It seems you've had extensive experience with small drug-like molecules. Why not start with a "smaller" problem, say describing a polymer using graphs? In any case, a search of "graph theory polymer composites" actually turned up some hits that could be relevant to you in terms of providing info on features that might be considered, but it seems you are interested only in describing bonding contacts using graph theory. A quick search did not turn up much on this specifically.

Comment: @Blade BTW rem to use handle if directing message at someone, otherwise these are likely to go unheard.